# why there is large difference in excecuting the codes?

Tags: python

[image]the picture is the task given:
this is my solution, I did how we used to solve the problem

```
 import math
    ab=int(input())
    bc=int(input())
    ac=(ab**2+bc**2)**0.5
    s=(ac/2)/bc
    theta=math.acos(s)
    theta_degrees=(theta*180)//math.pi
    print(str(int(theta_degrees))+ u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}")
```

this is one of the solutions

```
import math 
        AB = int(input()) 
        BC = int(input()) 
        print (str(int(round(math.degrees(math.atan2(AB,BC)))))+u"\N{DEGREE SIGN}")
```

My solution is only 1 out of 6 test cases. What is the reason why my code doesn't crack the answer and what is the difference between these 2 solutions? Is my code create some deviation between the steps?

Comment: They said to round, not to floor.

Comment: Also your math just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Angle BMC is usually not a right angle, so what you're doing with that arccos computation is invalid.

Comment: thank you : ). yea, my math is Lil bit bland. I solved it like a child ;)

Comment: You halve `(ab**2+bc**2)`, but Pythagoras would prefer a square root there. Then you compute theta using the `acos` of `.5 * ac / bc`, but unless I'm mistaken that would the arcsin instead of the arccos, if you want to do it this way? The second solution is much better. It solves it by extending BM to form the diagonal of the rectangle completed by mirroring ABC over the hypotenuse - the diagonal intersects AC exactly in the middle, so the angle becomes the arctan of AB and BC. Your math is not just 'bland', it's just plain wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: ✌thanks, dude! But one clarification,  in (ac=(ab**2+bc**2)**0.5) ,whether  **0.5 is this correct way to make a square root

Comment: I got it, what I made is a blunder, I got stuck to the diagram 